# Merge objects in array based on property

Tags: javascript

I have an array like so which i am trying to merge so any object that has the name property the same will after the merge contain a list of merged objects

```
var array = [ 
    {name: "One",
     myList: [Object1, Object2]
    },
    {name: "Two",
     myList: [Object3, Object4]
     },
     {name: "One",
     myList: [Object5, Object6]
     }
]
```

How do i merge the two 'One' objects so i get something like

```
var array = [ 
    {name: "One",
     myList: [Object1, Object2, Object5, Object6]
    },
    {name: "Two",
     myList: [Object3, Object4]
     }
]
```

looking to do this in vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you could remove the duplicate entries and organize the objects inside the `myList` array. Then, return an array of objects with specified keys, based on the ordered object from the first step.

```js
var array = [{name:"One",myList:['Object1','Object2']},{name:"Two",myList:['Object3','Object4']},{name:"One",myList:['Object5','Object6']}], obj = {};

array.forEach(function(v) {
  obj[v.name] = (obj[v.name] || []).concat(v.myList)
});

var arr = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(s,a) {
  s.push({name: a, myList: obj[a]});
  return s;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You can try `obj[v.name] = (obj[v.name] || []).concat(v.myList)`

Comment: @Rajesh Inside the foreach?

Comment: @Kinduser Yes. spread operator is part of ES6 and is not available in all browsers

Comment: @blu10 I think everything else would work. You can replace code I suggested inside forEach and it  should be good

Answer (score 3):

Using `reduce`:

```
var merged = array.reduce(function(list, obj) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].name == obj.name) {
            list[i].myList = list[i].myList.concat(obj.myList);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        list.push(obj);
    }

    return list;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `Lodash` with just [chain](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chain) and [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#reduce)

```
var array = [
    { name: "One", myList: ["Object1", "Object2"] },
    { name: "Two", myList: ["Object3", "Object4"] },
    { name: "One", myList: ["Object5", "Object6"] }
  ];

  const newArray = _.chain(array)
    .reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
      acc[currentValue.name] = (acc[currentValue.name] || []).concat(
        currentValue.myList
      );
      return acc;
    }, {})
    .reduce((acc, currentValue, key) => {
      acc.push({ name: key, myList: currentValue }); 
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .value();

  console.log(newArray);
```