# Merge objects with same first key value, so rest of key values will be added to merged object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I can't find answer to my question anywhere.

**What am I creating?**

I'm creating databases management panel with vue.js at front and node.js + mySQL at back.

There are 4 databases. Each databases row has `phone_number`, `e_mail`, `created`, `source_website` columns.

I have already did import of records from all of the databases. I pushed them into an array of objects.

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

I'd like to merge records with the same email and push each value from each repeated record to one merged record.

**Expected output**

Before:

```
[
    {
        "number": "111111111",
            "email": "test@test.com",
        "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
        "website": "http://firstwebsite.com",
        "id": 24,
    },
    {
        "number": "111222222",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
        "website": "http://secondwebsite.com",
        "id": 24,
    },
]
```

After:

```
[
    {
        "number": "111111111, 111222222",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
        "website": "http://firstwebsite.com, http://secondwebsite.com",
        "id": 24,
    },
]
```

Comment: Please show us what you already tried in order to solve your issue. Then we can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge objects in array based on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281272/merge-objects-in-array-based-on-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably be simplified, but it is working.

```js
let data = [{
    "number": "111111111",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
    "website": "http://firstwebsite.com",
    "id": 24,
}, {
    "number": "452",
    "email": "stack@overflow.com",
    "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
    "website": "http://first.com",
    "id": 28,
}, {
    "number": "111222222",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "created": "2019-02-18T15:01:18.000Z",
    "website": "http://secondwebsite.com",
    "id": 24,
}, {
    "number": "999",
    "email": "stack@overflow.com",
    "created": "2019-05-18T15:01:18.000Z",
    "website": "http://first.com",
    "id": 29,
}];

// Start with an object because I will use email property as key
// for an easier checking of which email has already been looped through
let result = {};

for (let i in data) {
    let item = data[i],
        // Here the checking that I talked above
        toPush = (result[item.email]) ? result[item.email] : {};
    
    for (let property in item) {
        let value = item[property];
        
        if (!toPush[property]) {
            toPush[property] = value;
        } else {
            // If the current value is not already in the value list,
            // we add it after a ", "
            if (`${toPush[property]}`.indexOf(value) === -1) {
                toPush[property] += `, ${value}`;
            }
        }
    }
    
    result[item.email] = toPush;
}

// As we want an array as final result
result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

@iArcadia , thank You very much. Your answer was very helpful.

I have modified this function a bit.
Main futures of the new code are:

- new merged record takes only one, newest date instead of few.
- new records receive new property's (e.g. `list_1`, `list_2` etc.) that depends on `website` property. It gives newsletter system administrator possibility to send newsletter to different lists.

New function below:

```
mergeRecords() {
  this.subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
    if(subscriber.website === 'lodzkietargi') {
      subscriber.lista_1 = 1;
    }
    else if(subscriber.website === 'targiwroclaw') {
      subscriber.lista_2 = 1;
    }
    else if(subscriber.website === 'slaskietargi') {
      subscriber.lista_3 = 1;
    }
    else if(subscriber.website === 'targi') {
      subscriber.lista_4 = 1;
    }
  });
  let result = {};
  let itemId = 1;
  for (let i in this.subscribers) {
    let item = this.subscribers[i],

    toPush = (result[item.email]) ? result[item.email] : {};
    item.id = itemId
    itemId += 1;
    if (toPush.created > item.created) {
      item.created = toPush.created;
    }
    for (let property in item) {
      let value = item[property];
      if (!toPush[property]) {
          toPush[property] = value;
      } else {
        if (property === 'website') {
            toPush.website += `, ${value}`;
        }
      }
    }
    result[item.email] = toPush;
  }

  result = Object.values(result);
  this.subscribers = result;
  console.log(result);
}
```

I still think that code could be better. There is to much if statements.
Anyway, it could be helpful for someone.
Once again, thank You very much. You helped me a lot.