# How to reduce an array while merging one of it's field as well

Tags: javascript

I have this,

```
var o = [{
  "id": 1, // its actually a string in real life
  "course": "name1",
  // more properties
}, 
{
  "id": 1, // its actually a string in real life
  "course": "name2",
  // more properties
}];
```

I want this,

```
var r = [{
  "id": 1, // its actually a string in real life
  "course": ["name1", "name2"],
}];
```

I am trying this,

```
var flattened = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  var current = a[i];
  if(flattened.)
}
```

but I am stuck, I am not sure what to do next, array will have more then 2 records but this was just an example.

THERE are more fields but I removed them for simplicity, I won't be using them in final array.

Comment: are the objects ordered by `id`?

Comment: @NinaScholz no, it's actually a string

Comment: @NickParsons i think it's better to call it a string in this scenario, sorry for confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object) and [Merge objects in array based on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you will get the data flattened in the shape you want

```js
const o = [
  {
    id: 1,
    course: "name1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    course: "name2"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    course: "name2"
  }
];

const r = o.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(x => x.id === current.id);
  if (index !== -1) {
    acc[index].course.push(current.course);
  } else {
    acc.push({id:current.id, course: [current.course]});
  }
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the array and find the object.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, course: "name1" }, { id: 1, course: "name2" }],
    flat = array.reduce((r, { id, course }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => id === o.id);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(temp = { id, course: [] });
        }
        temp.course.push(course);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(flat);
```

The same by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, course: "name1" }, { id: 1, course: "name2" }],
    flat = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { id, course }) => m.set(id, [...(m.get(id) || []) , course]), new Map),
        ([id, course]) => ({ id, course })
    );

console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.reduce` to create an object of keys, and then use that object to set keys to be of the `id`. This way you can add to the same `course` array by targetting the `id` of the object. Lastly, you can get the values of the object to get your result.

See example below:

```js
var o = [{
  "id": 1,
  "course": "name1",
  "foo": 1
}, 
{
  "id": 1,
  "course": "name2",
  "bar": 2
}];

var res = Object.values(o.reduce((acc, {id, course, ...rest}) => {
  if(id in acc) 
    acc[id] = {...acc[id], course: [...acc[id].course, course], ...rest};
  else acc[id] = {id, course: [course], ...rest};
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). This example works for any number of properties:

```js
const o = [
  { id: 1, course: 'name1', time: 'morning', topic: 'math' },
  { id: 1, course: 'name2', time: 'afternoon' },
  { id: 2, course: 'name3', time: 'evening' }
];

const result = o.reduce((out, { id, ...rest }) => {
  out[id] = out[id] || {};
  const mergedProps = Object.entries(rest).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    return { ...acc, [k]: [...(out[id][k] || []), v] };
  }, out[id]);
  out[id] = { id, ...mergedProps };
  return out;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If you only care about the `id` and `course` fields, you can simplify to this:

```js
const o = [
  { id: 1, course: 'name1', time: 'morning', topic: 'math' },
  { id: 1, course: 'name2', time: 'afternoon' },
  { id: 2, course: 'name3', time: 'evening' }
];

const result = o.reduce((out, { id, course }) =>
  ({ ...out, [id]: { id, course: [...((out[id] || {}).course || []), course] } })
, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to accumulate the results. Search in the current result (accumulator `a`) for an object (`el`) with the same id, if found, append course to existing object and return the same accumulator, otherwise put into the accumulator with `course` as an array.

```
var res = o.reduce((a, {id,course}) => {
    var found = a.find(el => el.id == id);
    return found ? found.course.push(course) && a : [...a, {id, course: [course]}];
}, []);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation or some description as to why this would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function merge(array, key = 'id') {
  const obj = {}
  
  for(const item of array) {
    const existing = obj[item[key]]
    if(existing) {
      for(const [name, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if(name === key) continue;
        
        if(existing[name]) {
          existing[name] = [ ...(existing[name].$custom ? existing[name] : [existing[name]]), value ]
          existing[name].$custom = true;
        } else {
          existing[name] = value;          
        }
      }
    } else {
      obj[item[key]] = { ...item }
    }
  }
  
  return Object.values(obj)
}

var o = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "single": "test"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "course": "name1",
  "multifield": "test"
}, 
{
  "id": 1,
  "course": "name2"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "newfield": "test"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "anotherid": "test",
  "array": [1,3,4]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "array": "text"
}];

console.log(merge(o))
```

Comment: My solution benefits are 
1. You can specify custom id key
2. Not merged properties are not arrays