# Merge objects in array of objects based on id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this
How to achieve output form of this array ?
Input:

```
[
 { meta_key: 'nickname', meta_value: 'testqa2', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'first_name', meta_value: 'TEST', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'last_name', meta_value: 'QA', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'nickname', meta_value: 'testqa10', id: '11' },
  { meta_key: 'first_name', meta_value: 'TEST', id: '11' },
  { meta_key: 'last_name', meta_value: 'QA', id: '11' }
]
```

Output

```
[
 {id:'10 , nickname:'testqa2 , first_name:'TEST' , last_name :'QA'},
 {id:'10 , nickname:'testqa10, first_name:'TEST' , last_name :'QA'}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge objects in array based on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281272/merge-objects-in-array-based-on-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using `reduce` like this

```js
const data = [
 { meta_key: 'nickname', meta_value: 'testqa2', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'first_name', meta_value: 'TEST', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'last_name', meta_value: 'QA', id: '10' },
  { meta_key: 'nickname', meta_value: 'testqa10', id: '11' },
  { meta_key: 'first_name', meta_value: 'TEST', id: '11' },
  { meta_key: 'last_name', meta_value: 'QA', id: '11' }
]


const result = Object.values(data.reduce((res, {id, meta_key, meta_value}) => {
  return {
    ...res,
    [id]: {
      id,
      ...res[id],
      [meta_key]: meta_value
    }
  
  }

}, {}))

console.log(result)
```